Find the natural number n for which the set $A_n$ has exactly 323 integers
the problem
For n a natural number we define $A_n=\{x\in \Bbb R \,|\,\,  |x+n+4|  \leq 3n-4\}$.  The natural number n for which the set $A_n$ has exactly 323 integers is....?
my idea
i absolutely have no idea what to do with this modulo so i decided to square it up and got to $x^2+n^2+16+2xn+8x+8n \leq 9n^2-24n  +16\implies x^2+n^2+2xn+8x+8n \leq 9n^2-24\implies 8n^2-32n-x^2-2xn-8x \geq 0$
i didnt know what to do forward
if it helps, after some brute forcing i got to the fact that the answer is 55.
hope one fo you can help me!  thanks!

@TonyK  Got it.  I figured we were restricting to the integers here.

Squaring is dangerous in such questions, because it can introduce spurious solutions. Better is to break the solution space into two parts, according as $x+n+4$ is positive or negative.

I'd consider looking at what happens for some small values of $n$. It may help get a handle on the problem.

Shifting $A_n$ doesn’t change it’s size.

You can split into two inequalities based on the sign of $x+n+4$, so when $x \ge -(n+4)$ the stuff inside the modulus is nonnegative so you can delete the modulus bars.  When $x \lt -(n+4)$ the content is negative and you have to negate it.  The two ranges of $x$ meet, so you should have one range of $x$ in the set.  What are the greatest and least $x$'s that work as formulas that depend on $n$?

$|x+n+4|  \leq 3n-4\iff -3n+4\le x+n+4\le3n-4\iff -4n\le x\le2n-8$ It follows that for $(4x)+(2x-8)+(1)=323\Rightarrow x=55$. The required number is $n=55$.

Since $n$ is a natural number, for $n\ge 2$ both sides in the inequality
$$
|x+n+4| \le 3n-4
$$
are positive, so this inequality is equivalent to the one  obtained after squaring. So we have equivalently:
$$
x^2 +2x(n+4) -(8n^2-32n)\le 0\ .
$$
Let $x_\pm=x_\pm(n)$ be the roots of the polynomial in $x$ on the L.H.S. above. They are:
$$
x_\pm=-(n+4)\pm\sqrt{(n+4)^2+(8n^2-32n)}
=-(n+4)\pm (3n-4)
$$
of course, as expected when factorizing our $(x+n+4)^2-(3n-4)^2$, and the sign of the polynomial function of second degree is negative in our case, iff $x$ is between the roots, including them. So there are so many such integer $x$ values as between $-(3n-4)$ and $+(3n-4)$, and counting them as they are negative, zero, or positive we obtain $(3n-4)+1+(3n-4)=6n-7$ integer values in $A_n$. When is this number equal to $323$? So $6n-7=323$... This gives the only chance $n=(323+7)/6=330/6=110/2=55$, and this number works.
